# Identify parent message Id in outlook reply mail mode

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

i am making a js outlook addin. Here I want to get the parent message id, if user trying to reply mail.

When user opens reply mail in compose mode, i want to extract parent message Id and do some analytics.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EWS for getting the job done. You can navigate through the conversation and find the latest one. See [How to: Get conversation items by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220497(v=exchg.80).aspx) for more information.

Comment: this is c# code. i want to do with javascript. how can i do ?

Comment: REST API can be used in any language.

Comment: It can be achieved through REST API now. If you need support of this feature in office outlook add-in api, please add your request here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. Learning about the new requirements add-in developers have helps us continue to enable great scenarios on our platform.  We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our uservoice page. 

Thanks for your feedback,
Outlook Engineering Team

Comment: "It can be achieved through REST API now" How? What calls? Surprised how hard it is to find this.

Comment: While I am able to use the REST api to get the messages that have the same conversarionId, I don't know how to find which email in the thread that this draft is in reply to.

Is there any way to determine this? I see the "ReplyTo" field, but it seems to always be blank.

Thanks,

Comment: In the Managed API it seems like there is a ParentConversationIndex on the ConversationNode, but that does not exist in the REST API for some reason.